# Simple Queries in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

what are the queries to do the following in Oracle?

1. get names of all views which are
   present ? (Similar to select * from
   view, but i want to get views not
   tables)
2. See source of a particular
   view.

Answer (score 6):

1. get names of all views:

   a. which are owned by the current user:

   ```
   SELECT view_name
   FROM USER_VIEWS;
   ```

   b. which are visible to the current user:

   ```
   SELECT view_name
   FROM ALL_VIEWS;
   ```

   c. which are present:

   ```
   SELECT view_name
   FROM DBA_VIEWS;
   ```
2. See source of a particular view

   SELECT text
   FROM xxx_VIEWS
   WHERE view_name = :myviewname;

(xxx can be USER, ALL or DBA)

[DBA_VIEWS](http://ss64.com/orad/DBA_VIEWS.html)

Comment: He may not have access to DBA_VIEWS. But USER_VIEWS also has the text column.

Comment: Also, there is ALL_VIEWS, which has all views visible to the current user.

Answer (score 2):

To see the definition of a view in sqlplus:

```
describe MY_VIEW;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will get the names of views in your schema.

```
select object_name
  from user_objects
 where object_type = 'VIEW'
```

The query for getting the view source?

```
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'VIEW_NAME', 'USERNAME')
 2     from dual
 3   /
```

Answer (score 0):

views owned by user

```
 select * from USER_VIEWS ;
```

check for oracle objects metadata

http://cisnet.baruch.cuny.edu/holowczak/oracle/sqlplus/

Answer (score 0):

```
1. select  OWNER,
 OBJECT_NAME,
 to_char(CREATED,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') created,
 status
from   dba_objects
where OWNER not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')
and OBJECT_TYPE='VIEW'
order by OWNER,OBJECT_NAME
```

2. select TEXT FROM DBA_VIEWS where OWNER ='owner_name' and VIEW_NAME= 'view_name'